# Laravel Authentication Trouble

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Having a bit of trouble authenticating users.
Here is my basic login function : http://pastebin.com/a92Mnb7C
Here is my HTML : http://pastebin.com/bmAnVSeA
The table name is users and I can connect to it.
A test user I have:
2   Testing     test@test.com   $2y$10$6stKxV9TSiqFfLPSRffKOO8.OTJs

I have tried with a hashed password and unhashed.

The auth mode is set to "database" not "equolent".
The auth table is set to "users".

Can anyone help suggest whats wrong or any troubleshoot help?
Would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field names aren't matching:

```
if(Input::has('login_email') AND Input::has('login_password')){
               ^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
                                                     ^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^
```

`login_email` != `email`, and `login_password` != `password`.

Comment: Hello, I changed this just before I posted. Prior to be experimenting with the fields, this wasn't working. I even replaced the "Input::get" with strings and variables matching the database information